# Spotlight search customizations

Tags: iphone, ios, spotlight, search, news.app

How do I customize the news sources in Spotlight suggestions?  I don't want to disable as others have answered.  I want to remove certain suggestions that require subscriptions to read the articles.  It is not totally location based.  I get results from LA Times and I'm somewhere Louisiana.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're asking for.  That's controlled by Apple and it's been a problem with that service for quite a while.  Hopefully, Apple will allow us to 'like' and 'dislike' news sources